# How to properly configure Exchange email account as incoming and outgoing in Frappe?

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, smtp, exchange-server, frappe

As of February 2023, Microsoft disabled SMTP authentification, so password-based logins don't work. A solution similar to GMail with user/application token seems difficult too as Microsoft tokens are multiple and don't seem to allow a similar behavior.

I managed to authenticate with Oauth2 with much difficulty. However, once I activate the incoming or the outgoing, I have an Authenticate Error so I am pretty sure there are still some parameters lacking.

I was expecting a tutorial similar to this one for Gmail: https://docs.erpnext.com/docs/v13/user/manual/en/setting-up/email/email_account_setup_with_gmail

---

Oauth would be the best stable way to fix this, but right now any working method would be enough.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission), it seems that you can enable/disable SMTP Auth.

Comment: The default security settings of the Microsoft organization needs to be turned off to do so. It can't be done in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There's this integration that makes Oauth setup with Microsoft easier. The readme has clear setup steps and all of the core functionality is restricted to the brief `callback.py` module.

https://github.com/castlecraft/microsoft_integration

Comment: It seems perfect, but how can I make it work? This module doesn't create any doctype and I don't see where to put the mentioned JSON social login key server side neither.